# Handling NULL value in ORACLE Table Query

Tags: database, oracle

I have a question regarding handling NULL value in a column in ORACLE Table.

So, when i query a table, i get this error message in every NULL value occurences

```
Notice: Undefined index: STATUS in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\AdminLTE\pages\tables\assignmenttable.php on line 481
```

my query is like this

```
SELECT MASTER_DRAWING.*, (SELECT PREPACKING_LIST.PACKING_STATUS FROM PREPACKING_LIST WHERE MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = PREPACKING_LIST.HEAD_MARK) STATUS FROM MASTER_DRAWING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :PROJNAME
```

My question is, how to handle NULL value so that when it sees a null value, it can return some value such as 0 or any string.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `NVL` to replace null with another value, but more likely, you have a problem in your `PHP` code.

Comment: @ammoQ i did try this `SELECT MASTER_DRAWING.*, (SELECT NVL(PREPACKING_LIST.PACKING_STATUS,'N/A') FROM PREPACKING_LIST WHERE MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = PREPACKING_LIST.HEAD_MARK) STATUS FROM MASTER_DRAWING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :PROJNAME` But its doesnt work

Comment: try `SELECT MASTER_DRAWING.*, NVL((SELECT PREPACKING_LIST.PACKING_STATUS FROM PREPACKING_LIST WHERE MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = PREPACKING_LIST.HEAD_MARK),'N/A') STATUS FROM MASTER_DRAWING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :PROJNAME` instead

Comment: Awesome, post it in an answer so i can rate this a a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MASTER_DRAWING.*,
   NVL((SELECT PREPACKING_LIST.PACKING_STATUS
      FROM PREPACKING_LIST
      WHERE MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = PREPACKING_LIST.HEAD_MARK),'N/A'
   ) STATUS
 FROM MASTER_DRAWING WHERE PROJECT_NAME = :PROJNAME
```